# Azure B2C redirecting to custom domain

Tags: reactjs, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn, msal.js

I am serving SPA application with Azure AD B2C integration from Storage Container.

Everything works correctly with this address in browser ******.web.core.windows.net.

However when we add custom domain and CDN Profile and serve it on e.g. pets.dev.com, user gets redirected to B2C for authorisation and comes back to address ******.web.core.windows.net.
It is an expected behaviour since that is the redirected URL set by the SPA app when redirecting user to B2C.

Though when we change the redirect URL to e.g. pets.dev.com the app goes into endless loop when coming back from B2C. It goes to pets.dev.com and immidietly gets send back to B2C, B2C (as the user is logged) sends it back to pets.dev.com and loop repeats.

Any ideas what is wrong with the setup?

On SPA app I am using React with react-azure-b2c wrapper for MSAL.